# Can I mount a volume at /Users on OS X?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, storage

I'm considering purchasing a SSD for my Macbook Pro. Unfortunately, I can't afford a large one, so I'm thinking of moving the current hard drive to the optical bay. On a Linux system, I would mount the second drive at /home. Given that Mac OS X Snow Leopard is Unix, I'm thinking it should be possible to do the same thing. Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, and it should work. A simpler solution though is to just put a symbolic link in /Users, pointing at your user directory on the new drive. I've done similar things in the past with multiple drives on an Xserve and it seems to work fine.

Yet another option: in `System Preferences` => `Accounts`, right-click on a user name and select `Advanced Options...` - you can then set the user's home directory location directly rather than using a symbolic link.

Comment: How would this work? Is Disk Utility able to specify the mount points when installing? I wouldn't trust a symlink as the automatic mount points can change in some cases.

Comment: Disks are mounted in a predictable way under OS X - everything other than the boot disk appears under /Volumes. So you could symlink from `/Users/fred` to `/Volumes/OtherDisk/Users/fred`, for example, and that is reliable in my experience.

Comment: Most of the time, that's true, but there can be cases where a disk will mount as `/Volumes/OtherDisk\ 2`. On top of that, why mess around with symlinks if the OS has the ability to mount volumes where you want them in the first place?